# Из того что мы знаем

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в предложении "*Из того что мы знаем*"?
Проблема возникла при перефразировании этой фразы в "...из известного нам..."

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **из того, что мы знаем.** Эта структура соответствует придаточному изъяснительному предложению, запятая ставится перед  союзным словом ЧТО.

В русском языке разные грамматические конструкции могут иметь практически одинаковый смысл, но при этом они оформляются **по своим собственным правилам**.